# Inverted commas or italics when you mouth something

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

I am wondering if it is better to use inverted commas or italics when you *mouth* something, rather than say it aloud.

E.g.

I cover the receiver and mouth *Sorry* to my friend.

Or is it better to go with:

I cover the receiver and mouth "Sorry" to my friend.

I am also wondering if *Sorry* should even have a capital letter or if it should be a small letter. Any thoughts?

Also, if someone's words sound in your head at some point later in a novel, should they be put in italics or inverted commas?

E.g.

I think back to what Jane told me yesterday: "He'll always be haunted by her."

Or:

I think back to what Jane told me yesterday. *He'll always be haunted by her.*

Any thoughts on what would be best would be greatly appreciated. I have checked the Chicago style guide and am still unsure.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not gonna post this as an answer because it's mostly personal opinion and observation, but in most literature I've read and the majority of examples of this kind of writing I've seen, as well as in my own writing, italics are used for dialogue that isn't actually being spoken. Thoughts, things being mouthed, etc. Quotations are reserved for those things which are actually spoken aloud, so as not to confuse the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much John. That is what I thought. I just recently saw it in inverted commas and second-guessed myself! Also, would you use a capital here: He mouthed *bye* or He mouthed *Bye*. I don't need a comma after mouth here I don't believe, but I am not 100% sure about the capital. Thank you!

Comment: A thread on grammarbook.com about this topic would suggest a consensus of capitalising as if you'd used quotes, so Bye rather than bye.

Comment: As a corollary to this some people might argue that mouthing words should still use quotes; I don't think there's a particular hard-and-fast rule there, so I would personally recommend using what seems the most natural for your writing style.

Comment: If you google "capitalisation in italicised thoughts" it's the first result.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will input this into my novel right now!